# CSS: Inverse of mask-image

Tags: html, css

I have am giving a png and I want the png to be cut out of the background.  mask-image leaves the section of the mask that is black, I need it to remove the section that is black and leave everything else.

[image]

The top example is what it does by default, what I need it to do is the bottom example.

Comment: Please put the code you have so far into a runnable snippet direct into the question. Please ensure that we can load the required images.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example